# SQL Server - looking for matches within names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, full-text-search

I'm using SQL Server 2005, I have names coming into a system and I want to compare them against a table to look for matches.  Any suggestions on how to match something like this:

The incoming value is something like "J.R. Thompson Corporation" 
while the value is "The Jim Ryan Thompson Company" in the database.

Comment: You'd need to setup Full-Text-Search synonyms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: It'd be interesting to see the results of running DIFFERENCE (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) on all these string pairs, order DESCending.

Answer (score 0):

Simply said - it can not be done. Even normalizing addresses is complex, and there you follow only specific rules (Str. for Street, for example). I was in a project doing that in germany 15 years ago and hell broke loose, so to say - because some places had special rules (m 4 = valid address in one city, for example, because the inner city is quandrants, or "Strasse des 14. July Appartement 3" broke our "first numer is end of street name" rules).

The whole thing gets woirse - in your xample "J.R." and "Jim Ryan" may or may not be the same. There are some rules you can set up, and it gets a lot easier with addresses (same address means that at the end the name matching can ebe looser) but in general this is not a reasible approach. Even spelling correction will not catch that. There simply is no way to normalize that without artificial intelligence having internet access to use google to find out whether it matches. Yes, you may fget a 20% or 30% hit rate, but that leaves you with a TON of errors left and right and is likely less than useless from a business point of view.

You need at least one standardized identifier you can use to nail down the selection. House numbers, phone numbers, anything that can be standardized easier and then provides an achor for the name matching algo.

Answer (score -1):

Without doing full text search (which is designed to do these things), you can do this in a simple way and get close by just replacing the spaces and periods with % wild cards and putting % at the start and end of the string:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(50) = 'J.R. Thompson Corporation'

SELECT * 
FROM Company 
WHERE Name LIKE '%' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@input, '.', '%'), ' ', '%') + '%'
```

It is important to note that doing any sort of LIKE search where you have a leading `%` symbol will not benefit from an index on that column.

Note this still will not pick up things like "company' meaning 'corporation' as in your example.

Comment: This will not work with the inputs that the OP provided. "JR" and "JimRyan" are not matches.

Comment: actually it will work with J.R. (the OP has a . between J and R, without this it won't work no) and JimRyan because it will become '%J%R%', it won't work for Company and Corporation as I say at the bottom.

Comment: That was a very specific example. What if it were reversed, and he wanted to find J.R. when the parameter was JimRyan? I don't think you're fully grasping what's being requested - it's a synonym / fuzzy search problem, not a LIKE problem.